# setState() method call when using mocha + enzyme is not affecting the state of component

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, react-redux

When I use setSate() method on compiled component, the state is not being set.
The control is taking the state from the production code and not the state assigned from the test. Find the code below.

```
const wrapper = mount(<BookFlight />
    wrapper.setState({ cabins: {
          fields: [
            {
              label: 'Economy',
              value: 'econ',
              name: 'cabin',
              type: 'radio'
            },
            {
              label: 'Business',
              value: 'business',
              name: 'cabin',
              type: 'radio'
            },
            {
              label: 'First',
              value: 'first',
              name: 'cabin',
              type: 'radio'
            }
          ]
        }})
        expect(wrapper.state().cabins.fields.length).toBe(3)
```

Comment: When we do the above expect it's hitting a function that is the value for "cabins" key in the object - the function call is present in the code and the one we defined in test is not been taken

Comment: could you provide a more complete example? Include the component BookFlight and also ensure your code and example above have the correct amount of parenthesis (you are missing one after `mount(BookFlight`

Comment: You could try to `shallow` mount instead of deep mounting, which might make the problem easier to spot.